# Change Default Application For Any File

Tags: java, desktop-application

I Want to know if i can change default application for a particular file like if i have set .mp4 files to be open with VLC. Now when I open a .mp4 file via java it should ask me to open with VLC or other relating applications i.e: Windows Media Player.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the default application isn't Java, but the operating system's feat, in your case Windows. You can configure Windows to change this using '[choose default program](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/18539/windows-7-change-default-programs)' option.

If you were just looking to open the file from within your java application, then you could use [Desktop.open(fileName)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) or even a simple [Runtime.exec(fileName)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).